# jQuery UI Calendar setDate persistent on PostBack ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery datepicker. My function looks like this:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#datePicker").datepicker({
            minDate: -10,
            maxDate: "0D"
        });
        $("#datePicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    });
```

I am have the default date set to today's date as shown below. 
We are using ASP.Net in conjunction with our calender.

We want the ability to have the user select a previous date than today, which is what the function currently does, but after the form submission we want the date the user selected to persist and not change back to the default. From my understanding a submission through ASP.Net form causes a postback and refreshes the page, which in turn refreshes the calendar. How can we have the calendar date persist to what they selected after a form submission.

thanks,